# How to prove this identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$$
x_1=- \frac{b\, t}{\left(a + e\, t\right)}, \\
x_2=- \frac{c\, s\, \left(a + e\, t\right)}{\left(a\, b + a\, f\, s - b\, h\, s\, t + e\, f\, s\, t\right)}, \\
x_3=- \frac{q\, \left(a\, b + a\, f\, s - b\, h\, s\, t + e\, f\, s\, t\right)}{\left(a + e\, t\right)\, \left(a + e\, q + e\, t + h\, q\, s\right)}, \\
y_1=- \frac{c\, q\, s}{\left(b\, q + b\, t + f\, q\, s\right)}, \\
y_2=- \frac{\left(b\, q + b\, t + f\, q\, s\right)}{\left(a + e\, q + e\, t + h\, q\, s\right)}, \\
y_3=- \frac{b\, c\, s\, t\, \left(a + e\, q + e\, t + h\, q\, s\right)}{\left(b\, q + b\, t + f\, q\, s\right)\, \left(a\, b + a\, f\, s - b\, h\, s\, t + e\, f\, s\, t\right)}.
$$
Then by direct computation, we have $x_1+x_2+x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3$. My questions is, could we prove this identity without direct computation but use some more elegant method? Thank you very much.

$x_1$ depends on $t$, $x_2$ depends on $s$, $x_3$ depends on $q$, $y_1$ depends on $qs/(t+q)$, $y_2$ depends on $t+q$, $y_3$ depends on $ts/(t+q)$. Let 
$$\phi_1(t)=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & t & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right), \phi_2(t)=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & t \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right).$$
Then we have 
$$
\phi_1(t)\phi_2(s)\phi_1(q)=\phi_2(sq/(t+q))\phi_1(t+q)\phi_2(ts/(t+q)).
$$ 
Therefore I think that maybe there is some elegant way to prove that $x_1+x_2+x_3=y_1+y_2+y_3$.

Comment: Do you have any more elegant way to write down $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$?

Comment: Don't $a,b,c,...,e$ appear in the $\phi_i(t)$'s?